# Run Blender from CLI with GUI

Tags: python, scripting, command-line, windows

Hello dear blender community,

I am trying to automate a few tasks in Blender, and trigger their execution from the command line like this:
`blender %file% --python myScript.py`. My script is calling an installed Addon developed by someone else. This addon is calling at several points in the code `bpy.context.area` to set the context for some `bpy.ops.` operators.
This is were my struggles start. As I am calling blender from the CMD *without* the `--background` argument, I (possibly falsely) assumed that the context and ops are unaffected, sadly though I cannot force blender to set a `bpy.context.area`.
I tried to set a context using this:

```
for window in bpy.context.window_manager.windows:
    screen = window.screen
    for area in screen.areas:
        if area.type == 'VIEW_3D':
            override = {'window': window, 'screen': screen, 'area': area}
            bpy.ops.screen.screen_full_area(override)
            break
```

but it fails on setting an area, and `bpy.context.area` remained a NoneType.
Is there a way I can call blender from CMD, let it first draw a GUI and only call my script headlessly once the `bpy.context.area` is no longer a NoneType?
I tried naively a `time.sleep` statement, and tried different ways of setting a context to one of the areas from `bpy.data.screens['xx'].areas[0]`, but failed so far.
Does anyone have a CLI argument or a snippet I can add to my code to create a `bpy.context.area`?

I am running Windows and Blender 2.93.1.

Many thanks!!

Answer (score -1):

you can override context in blender is your script also calling context dependent if so you can override it with something like this .

```
import bpy
 
override_context = bpy.context.copy()
area = [area for area in bpy.context.screen.areas if area.type == "VIEW_3D"][0]
override_context['window'] = bpy.context.window
override_context['screen'] = bpy.context.screen
override_context['area'] = area
override_context['region'] = area.regions[-1]
override_context['scene'] = bpy.context.scene
override_context['space_data'] = area.spaces.active
 
bpy.ops.wm.toolbar(override_context)
```

also readup more here https://b3d.interplanety.org/en/context-override/

Comment: Are you sure this is the answer to the question above? I don't think it helps to acquire bpy.context.area when a python script was running in the background.